# Erro ao debugar no TDS 11.2 (Eclipse) no Linux Mint 18

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, mint, advpl

Configurei o debug com o caminho do smartclient.exe (uso via wine), a compilação funciona, só o debug que dá um erro de permissão no java.

```
Iniciando TOTVS Application
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Exception occurred executing command line.
    org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:852)
    org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:821)
    com.totvs.tds.debug.launcher.AdvPLLaunchDelegate.internalLaunch(AdvPLLaunchDelegate.java:361)
    com.totvs.tds.debug.launcher.AdvPLLaunchDelegate.launch(AdvPLLaunchDelegate.java:85)
    ...
Causado por
        Cannot run program "/home/eduardo/Área de Trabalho/Acessos a Clientes/smartclient UNS/SmartClient.exe" (in directory "/home/eduardo/Área de Trabalho/Acessos a Clientes/smartclient UNS"): error=13, Permissão negada
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/eduardo/Área de Trabalho/Acessos a Clientes/smartclient UNS/SmartClient.exe" (in directory "/home/eduardo/Área de Trabalho/Acessos a Clientes/smartclient UNS"): error=13, Permissão negada
    java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:848)
    org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:821)
    com.totvs.tds.debug.launcher.AdvPLLaunchDelegate.internalLaunch(AdvPLLaunchDelegate.java:361)
    com.totvs.tds.debug.launcher.AdvPLLaunchDelegate.launch(AdvPLLaunchDelegate.java:85)
    ...
Causado por
        error=13, Permissão negada
java.io.IOException: error=13, Permissão negada
    java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:848)
    org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:821)
    com.totvs.tds.debug.launcher.AdvPLLaunchDelegate.internalLaunch(AdvPLLaunchDelegate.java:361)
    com.totvs.tds.debug.launcher.AdvPLLaunchDelegate.launch(AdvPLLaunchDelegate.java:85)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Não utilize no caminho do smartclient diretórios que contenham espaço e acentuação. 
De preferencia tambem para low case.

Comment: Tentei com um caminho mais simples e sem espaços, continua com o mesmo erro.